# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API scaffold identity controllers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer 6

I'm looking for a way to scaffold api controllers for identity pages. I saw [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) however, it says only about razor and mvc projects.

Is there a way I can scaffold those controllers?

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood the [idea of ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355229/net-core-identity-vs-identityserver4) Could be mark as solved

Comment: Hello from 2 years later. So is it possible to scaffold controllers for ASP.NET Core Web API?